# How to call an array in SOAP with SAVON 2 in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, api, soap, savon

request via SOAP UI

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:arr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:GetLastDayRounds>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:glIds>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <arr:int>7910</arr:int>
            <arr:int>791524</arr:int>
            <arr:int>5613</arr:int>
         </tem:glIds>
      </tem:GetLastDayRounds>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

respond via SOAP UI

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <GetLastDayRoundsResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <GetLastDayRoundsResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/GL.WS" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <a:Message i:nil="true"/>
            <a:Rounds xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/GL.WS.Entities">
               <b:Round>
                  <b:AdjustedScore>91</b:AdjustedScore>
               </b:Round>
                 <b:Round>
                  <b:AdjustedScore>92</b:AdjustedScore>
               </b:Round>
                <b:Round>
                  <b:AdjustedScore>191</b:AdjustedScore>
               </b:Round>
            </a:Rounds>
            <a:Status>Success</a:Status>
         </GetLastDayRoundsResult>
      </GetLastDayRoundsResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

This is how I made the connection:

```
url = "http://api.wsdl.address"
    @client = Savon.client(
        wsdl: url,
        namespace: "http://tempuri.org/",
        env_namespace: :soapenv,
        log: true, # set true to switch on logging
        log_level: :debug,
        pretty_print_xml: true,
        open_timeout: 3000000,
        read_timeout: 3000000
    )
```

**Now this is what I think my SAVON 2 call should be:**

```
response = @client.call(:get_last_day_rounds, message: {"tns:glIds" => [7910,791524]})
```

But I get internal error form the supplier. If I test this via SOAP UI I get the result and all fine, however I cant figure it out how to do it via SAVON 2.

Thanks.

SAVON 2 Log:

At the request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <tns:GetLastDayRounds>
      <tns:glIds>7910</tns:glIds>
      <tns:glIds>791524</tns:glIds>
    </tns:GetLastDayRounds>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

respond:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <s:Fault>
      <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:InternalServiceFault</faultcode>
      <faultstring xml:lang="en-AU">The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the &lt;serviceDebug&gt; configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.</faultstring>
    </s:Fault>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

---

**I tried this too:**

```
response = @client.call(:get_last_day_rounds, message: { "tns:glIds" => { "int" => [79124,123] } } )
```

SAVON Log:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <tns:GetLastDayRounds>
      <tns:glIds>
        <int>791524</int>
        <int>123</int>
      </tns:glIds>
    </tns:GetLastDayRounds>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I got the the following error

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <s:Fault>
      <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:InternalServiceFault</faultcode>
      <faultstring xml:lang="en-AU">The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the &lt;serviceDebug&gt; configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.</faultstring>
    </s:Fault>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: you should provide the output of your logs.

Comment: Here you go mate. I added the log.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it. (In case someone use it)

The namespace needs to be changed.

So the call will be:

```
 def make_connection
    url = "http://api.wsdl.link"
    @client = Savon.client(
        wsdl: url,
        namespaces: {
            "xmlns:tem" => "http://tempuri.org/",
            "xmlns:arr" =>  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"
        },
        env_namespace: :soapenv,
        log: true, # set true to switch on logging
        log_level: :debug,
        pretty_print_xml: true,
        open_timeout: 3000000,
        read_timeout: 3000000
    )
 end
```

Now when I call:

```
response = @client.call(:get_last_day_rounds, message: {"tns:glIds" => { "arr:int" => [5613,79810] } })
```

I get the result

Cheers